# After installed eaccelerator server return 500 error

Tags: php, eaccelerator

I installed eAccelerator
this is my eaccelerator.ini

```
extension="eaccelerator.so"
eaccelerator.shm_size="32"
eaccelerator.cache_dir="/var/cache/eaccelerator"
eaccelerator.enable="1"
eaccelerator.optimizer="1"
eaccelerator.check_mtime="1"
eaccelerator.debug="0"
eaccelerator.filter=""
eaccelerator.shm_max="0"
eaccelerator.shm_ttl="0"
eaccelerator.shm_prune_period="0"
eaccelerator.shm_only="0"
eaccelerator.compress="1"
eaccelerator.compress_level="9"
```

but after installed eAccelerator I got 500 errors from server. Then I changed /etc/sysctl.conf (set kernel.shmmax = 536870912 and use command sysctl -p) and changed eaccelerator.ini (eaccelerator.shm_size="32")
And I again got 500 errors from server.

Comment: Anything interesting in the logfile?

Comment: apache error.log contains (104)Connection reset by peer: mod_fcgid: error reading data from FastCGI server [Thu May 08 18:34:39 2014] [error] [client 83.167.106.104] Premature end of script headers: index.php